# Tricking a Unix Commandline Program into Accepting a File Stream

Tags: pipe, unix

Hypothetical situation. I have a command line program in *nix (linux, BSD, etc.).  It was written so that you pass it a text file as an argument

```
$ program file.txt
```

Run the program, it looks at the text in `file.txt`.

Is it possible to "trick" this program into accepting input from a file stream rather than reading a  file via disk?  I'm pretty comfortable using unix pipes to **do** stuff, but there's still something a little mysterious about their internals that make it so I can't say (definitively) yes or not to the above question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash` lets you do this:

```
program <(otherprogram)
```

This uses the output of `otherprogram` as the contents of a file passed to `program`.

Comment: That's pretty neat.  What's it called, and is is possible to use if hte program accepts TWO different file paths? (something like diff)

Comment: Process substitution, and yes, you can use... up to 60 or so I think.

Comment: Sweet (more info here for the curious http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

Comment: Piping a file into a process's stdin is not the same as a process taking a filename and explicitly opening that file.

Comment: @Ether: Try again. This doesn't pipe it into stdin.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in [named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe):

```
mkfifo myPipe
program myPipe &
anotherProgram > myPipe
```

is equivalent to:

```
anotherProgram | program
```

Answer (score 1):

if your `program` is not coded to accept standard input, it won't work even if you use named pipes or process substitution

Comment: I think 1ch1gO is saying that using a named pipe will only work if the program is written to work on a stream.  You can pass a named pipe as an argument, but if the program tries to seek it will very likely fail.  Often, programmers are sloppy and do not check if a seek failed, so the program may fail in unusual ways.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the shell-managed trickery of the other answers:

Some unix systems have the special files `/dev/stdin`, and you can run e.g.

```
otherprogram | program /dev/stdin
```

Others (e.g. linux) may have `/proc/self/fd/0` which may be used the same way.

Both of these will fail if `stdin` is closed before the file on the command line is opened, but this will be an extremely rare occurrence.  Much more likely will be it failing because the program expects to `seek()` the file, which does not work on pipes.

If your shell is zsh, you have another option.

```
program =(otherprogram)
```

Which will do all the bother of setting up a temporary input file and removing it after `program` terminates.  This will work with `seek()`, but may temporarily take more space.